# Printing NSSet inside enumerateObjectsUsingBlock

Tags: ios, objective-c

I need to display contents of an object "literature" in my project. I know this might need more details but I am already displaying literature.name(first NSLog) and number of childLiteratures(2nd NSLog) but i do not know how can I print the names of childliteratures which is NSSet.

```
LiteratureFetcher* literatureFetcher = [[LiteratureFetcher alloc]init];
NSArray* apps = [literatureFetcher appLiteratures];

[apps enumerateObjectsUsingBlock:^(Literature* literature, NSUInteger idx, BOOL *stop) {
        NSLog(@"%@",literature.name); -->> returns correct folder name
        NSLog(@"%lu",(unsigned long)literature.childLiteratures.count); -->> returns correct file counts in a folder
}];
```

UPDATE:

This was solved by iterating again over literature.childliteratures.

Answer (score 0):

You can format the `childLiteratures` property using `%@`.  `NSLog` will print the entire contents of the set.  Example:

```
NSSet *set = [NSSet setWithObjects:@"blue", @"green", @"red", nil];
NSLog(@"set = %@", set);
```

Output:

```
2013-02-13 16:41:34.505 testApp[996:c07] set = {(
    red,
    green,
    blue
)}
```

Comment: I tried this NSLog(@"%@",literature.childLiteratures); but log shows Relationship 'childLiteratures' fault on managed object.. Shouldn't it just print the contents?

Comment: You need to make Core Data turn the fault into a real object.  (This is called firing the fault.)  Did you try printing the set after printing its count (in separate calls to `NSLog`)?

Comment: Yes. I can now print the files inside the folder.updated the original code. thanks..